# How to run batch script during windows boot?

Tags: batch-file, operating-system, format, boot, drive

I have a batch command (script) that format operating system drive, but as you know I can't format this drive in after a windows started, so I want to execute this script during windows boot (Black Screen), how can be done ?

Thanks

Comment: check runonce registry keys - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but for security reasons, you cannot.

The best way is to create a bootable device (USB or CD-ROM) and include the script on it.

Better add a confirmation in red (or two) before running the format, though.

Alternate way: boot the windows 7 installation CD, and type "ctrl+F10" (or is it shift+F10?). You get an admin cmd prompt, and have then access to all low level stuff: fdsisk, format...

Of course you may have to get access to BIOS settings to be able to do that (change boot priority).